Using free() with data structures
I am not from a computer science background and have been trying to learn Data Structures using C programming.
I have made some binary tree programs and realised that I have used malloc() left and right (pun intended :))  without ever using free() because I don't know how many nodes I have actually created.
My question is rather basic and almost stupid. Do I have to write a function similar to the print function to visit each node of the tree and free it individually or just free(root) will be enough since all the subsequent pointers will be lost anyway?

Of course free only one node ( root) will be not enough and memory leak. You need free every allocated node

The rule is simple: for every malloc call, you should have a correlative free call (with the address you got from that malloc).

"Do I have to write a function similar to the print function to visit each node of the tree and free it individually" Yes this is the normal and expected thing to do.

The memory will automatically be freed when the program exits, so you don't have to call free if you're willing to just let the memory be occupied until the end of the program.

Once you free memory you cannot safely access it again, so in the case of a linked list, you might have to free the nodes in reverse order, starting at the tail.

@JohnGordon note that the C language doesn't guarantee that memory will be freed on process exit; that is up to the OS to implement, or not.  Therefore portable code shouldn't assume that leaking memory is okay.

You could get around it by allocating a huge block of memory at start of the program, and creating your own my_malloc() function to dole out pieces of that huge memory block.  Then when finished, you only need to free that one huge block you allocated in the beginning.  It's arguably very bad practice and having a very bad motive, but it's great to know there is always another way to do something in C, and possibly a great learning experience as you work out the code for it.

@JeremyFriesner: The number of systems where the o/s does not clean up after programs is vanishingly small for most programmers.  There might be a few specialized fields where that's a problem, but you'd know if you're working in one of those fields.

@gregspears I'd argue that that approach is the only valid one for allocating large amounts of smallish (<1KB) heterogeneous objects. Trees, lists, etc. are a perfect use case; you allocate a number of items in one go and then release the block when no items in the block remain in use. Allocating and releasing individual items will then be orders of magnitude faster than otherwise.

@JonathanLeffler you'd know if you were working on one yourself, but if you're writing a library that is designed to be portable, you won't know where it might get used by other people in the future.

When using malloc() in C to allocate memory for nodes in a binary tree, calling free(root) will not automatically free the memory of the child nodes. The tree structure consists of pointers, so while root will be freed, the left and right child pointers may still point to memory that has not been deallocated.
To properly free all the nodes, you should traverse the tree and free each node individually. This is typically done using a post-order traversal (where you visit the left and right children before freeing the current node).
example of how you might implement this:
void freeTree(struct Node* root) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return;

    freeTree(root->left);  // Free left subtree
    freeTree(root->right); // Free right subtree
    free(root);            // Free current node
}

Note:
if the binary tree is highly unbalanced (i.e., resembling a linked list), this recursive approach could lead to a stack overflow due to deep recursion. In such case we can use an iterative approach, such as using a stack to simulate the recursive calls, or by flattening the tree into a linked list structure and freeing the nodes iteratively.

This answer is acceptable when the tree is balanced, i.e. there will never be a branch several thousand nodes deep. Otherwise, this approach can result in a stack overflow.

if the binary tree is highly unbalanced (i.e., resembling a linked list), this recursive approach could lead to a stack overflow due to deep recursion. In such case we can use an iterative approach, such as using a stack to simulate the recursive calls, or by flattening the tree into a linked list structure and freeing the nodes iteratively.

@user30482 While you are correct that recursion is evil in general, something containing that much data should probably not be stored in a BST to begin with, but maybe a hash table etc.

@Lundin BST makes a lot more sense than a hash table when you want to keep the data in a particular order and to be able to iterate over the elements in that order. Unbalanced BSTs are useful as ordered data structures for thread- and interrupt-safe contexts.
